# Why is this giving me an MRO error?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm using Django 1.8rc1.  When I try to do a `makemigrations` with this models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class TrackedModel(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateField()
    modified_date = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    due_date = models.DateField()
    complete_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
```

I am getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases Model, TrackedModel
```

I can't even see where it would be getting confused over methods with such a simple abstract model.  In case you're wondering, the Project model is inheriting from `models.Model` in the example but that was just to troubleshoot -- ultimately I want Project to inherit from `TrackedModel`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out.  The migration history got me again.  I had to clear out the files in my app's `migrations` folder.  Apparently it had stored a previous set of models that were not set up right, during a previous migration.